# Oracle APEX Interactive Grid New Row is not editable

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an interactive grid in Oracle APEX. When I click "Add Row" it adds a row, but that row is not editable. How do I make it so that when a row is added, it is editable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Processing section of the Page Designer, find the Processing item that saves that interactive grid. Make sure that Setting "Lock Row" is set to "No" rather than "Yes."